# write listener when application close

Tags: android, listener

I want to write code when application close. I want to write listener for application. I have created `Application` class but does not find any appropriate method as like `onCreated` and `onDestroy` method in activity..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

It seems the `Application` class has no capabilities to do that. (dont get confuse with `onTerminate`).

The problem is, why dont you write the code you want to run in `onDestroy` of your `Activity`?

What is your case, so destroying the `Activity` does not mean closing the `Application`?

You might consider to read this :

[When to use and not to use the android Application class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197800/when-to-use-and-not-to-use-the-android-application-class)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is ... there aren't!

The concept of "application close" is very diffuse: An application is a set of activities, services, etc... and a lot of things may keep the application alive.

You can't even guess when (or if) an activity `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` will be called.

Even calling `activity.finish()` doesn't mean any of those methods would be called instantly. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html .

But there's sure a better place to do those things you have to do. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

I actually done something very simple but you might call it annoying.
I added a boolean variable called isIntent in my activity.
than i overrided onResume like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    this.isIntent = false;
    super.onResume();
}
```

then, I did the following in onPause(onStop might work as well):

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!isIntent){
        //application closed
        isIntent = false;
    }
}
```

now every time you start activty you gotta set isIntent to true. you can also override startActivity like so:

```
    @Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    isIntent = true;
    super.startActivity(intent);
}
```

but I have to warn you I didn't override startActivity so it's on you.