# Open a App when another app close

Tags: android, launch

I need to open my android application when user close the opened google map application. Is there any possibilities to accomplish this kind of thing in android ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems there no way to identify when an app has closed.
Take a look at this:

[write listener when application close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943182/write-listener-when-application-close)